# Как правильно использовать существующий объект одного класса в описании другого класса на C++

Tags: c++, классы, наследование, микроконтроллеры

Я учусь использовать С++ для программирования микроконтроллеров.
И не могу понять, как выстроить правильно логику программы на С++

Расскажу на конкретном примере.
Допустим, я создал класс для обработки данных поступающих с UART (последовательный порт)
Класс представляет собой кольцевой буфер и несколько методов для работы с ним.
Методы самые простые: сохранить байт в буфер, вытащить байт из буфера, проверить буфер на пустоту, очистить буфер и т.д.

На основе класса я создал объект.
И проблема в том что этот объект должен быть только один, а использоваться он должен во всей программе в том числе и в других классах.

Объектом кольцевого буфера я пользуюсь и в прерывании (что бы положить туда пришедший байт) и в программе (например, для проверки его пустоты), а так же в классе для обработки сообщений и в некоторых других классах.
То есть, существующий объект должен использоваться как самостоятельно, так и в составе других классов.

К примеру, я хочу создать класс обработки принимаемых данных и в этом классе мне нужно как-то организовать взаимодействие с уже существующим объектом кольцевого буфера.
Наследование, дружба не вариант, так как при этом создастся еще один объект кольцевого буфера, а это не допустимо.

Получается, что если я создаю класс, где нужно как то взаимодействовать с буфером, то прямо в описании класса мне нужно использовать уже существующий объект.
Но, на сколько я понимаю, описание класса не должно каким-либо образом ссылаться на уже созданный объект.

Или такое допустимо?
Как быть в таких ситуациях?

Comment: Про синглтон погуглите, и вообще про паттерны проектирования.
Почитайте учебник типа книги Джеффа Элджера https://www.livelib.ru/book/1000218066-c-biblioteka-programmista-sbornik-dzheff-eldzher

Желательно все это изучать не на микроконтроллере, потому что МК добавляет своей специфики, замучаетесь разгребать

Comment: Попробуйте в конструктор всех Ваших классов, где нужен кольцевой буфер, добавить в качестве аргумента указатель (лучше `std::shared_ptr`) на объект этого буфера. И передавайте указатель на этот объект при создании объектов других классов. Только, если у Вас присутствует параллелизм, учитывайте возможность одновременного обращения разных объектов к буферу.